# Flexbox Horizontal List

Tags: flexbox, css

Boa tarde pessoal!

Estou querendo alinhar uma lista `ul` de forma que seus `li` fiquem a esquerda e o último `li` fique a direita. Não estou conseguindo fazer isso, alguém poderia me ajudar.

Eu poderia fazer isso de forma mais fácil se eu separasse essa `li` dessa `ul` mas eu queria manter junto.

Tentei pôr  o justify-self diretamente no úlimo  também mas não deu
Eu tentei conforme segue abaixo e não deu certo:

HTML

```
 <ul class="lista-menu">
    <a><li class="funcionarios">Funcionários</li></a>
    <a href="clientes.html"><li class="clientes">Clientes</li></a>
    <a href="produtos.html"><li class="produtos">Produtos</li></a>
    <a href="servicos.html"><li class="servicos">Serviços</li></a>
    <a><li class="financeiro">Financeiro</li></a>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
.lista-menu {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.financeiro {
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu HTML tem um erro de semântica que vc precisa corrigir, o filho direto da `<ul>` tem que ser a `<li>` e não o `<a>`

Depois, no CSS, usando `Flexbox`, para vc alinha no `eixo X` um filho de um *conteiner flex*, se usa `margin` e não `justyfy`

Repare abaixo, que ao colocar `margin-left: auto` no último filho ele vai colar na direita do container pai

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.lista-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  padding: 0;
}

.financeiro {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista-menu">
  <li class="funcionarios"><a>Funcionários</a></li>
  <li class="clientes"><a href="clientes.html">Clientes</a></li>
  <li class="produtos"><a href="produtos.html">Produtos</a></li>
  <li class="servicos"><a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
  <li class="financeiro"><a>Financeiro</a></li>
</ul>
```